# curl or file_get_contents not working

Tags: php, curl, wamp, wampserver, file-get-contents

I have some problems when i send posts requests.
I execute the page `http://localname.local/test` with this script and the page `http://localname.local/directory/page.php` get a json data.

```
$url = "http://localname.local/directory/page.php";

$post = [
    "key1" => "hello",
    "key2" => 885,
];

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($post),
        'timeout' => 10
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);


if ( $result === false ) {
    // Handle error
    return null;
}
else
    return $result;
```

But after 10 secondes, the script get the message :

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://localname.local/directory/page.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in D:\ ... \html\test.php on line X

The page.php works, I can send posts requests with my browser as a client but php (or wamp) can't access or send requests to its own pages.

I got PHP 7.1.7, Apache 2.4.23 on wamp 3.0.9 and the option `allow_url_fopen` is on.

Edit:
for **CURL**

```
public static function get_content($post)
{
    $url = "http://localname.local/directory/page.php";
    
    $query = http_build_query($post);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10); // Tell cURL that it should only spend X seconds trying to connect to the URL in question.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); // A given cURL operation should only take X seconds max.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // returns data to function
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    
    if ( curl_errno($curl) )
        throw new Exception(curl_error($curl));

    curl_close($curl);
    
    return $data;
}
```

get

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received in D:\ ... \html\test.php on line X
>
> Exception: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Comment: Does `test.php` typically (or even sometimes) take more than five seconds to run?

Comment: No it is fast to run. The WAMP configuration is at 30 seconds but I have to wait too long before having control over the server. :/

Comment: The problem is just an access error I think. Is it possible that WAMP can't access its own domain name? I run this on localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**THE REAL PROBLEM**

1. `test.php` use the `session_start()`
2. `test.php` launch a `POST request` on the `page.php`
3. `page.php` use the `session_start()` ***<<< freeze***

We can't use 2 sessions PHP at same time. The session is locking and create infinite loop.

Thank you guys for helping me find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

For file_get_contents() to open URLs you must enable the setting [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) in your php.ini file.

Security wise i would advise you to achieve what you are doing with [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php):

```
function get_content($url,$post){
    $query = http_build_query($post);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // returns data to function
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$query);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    // if you want to display error messages, do it before curl_close()
    //echo curl_errno($ch); // if you want to display error number
    //echo curl_error($ch); // if you want to display error message
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

echo get_content('http://localname.local/directory/page.php');
```

Comment: Get `Warning: curl_errno(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource in D:\ ... \html\test.php on line X`

Comment: That error is caused because you are using `curl_errno()` after `curl_close()` you need to keep any error handling before `curl_close($curl)`.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry. Thanks but now the error is `Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received in D:\ ... \html\test.php on line X`  But I think the problem is a refusal to communicate to himself (to his own domain name) is it possible?

Comment: That is because your page.php is taking too long to process your request. You need to find the bottleneck in there. Are you running a loop over something? What are you doing in that code? You can set curl to timeout later using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30);` (30 seconds) and see if you get back anything. But obviously will have to look into the cause on page.php.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to increase CURLOPT_TIMEOUT time

Comment: No, sorry, either it's the PHP script that stops after 30 seconds, or it's the CURL query that stops with the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT time. The script is fast in localhost